# H2 database isClosed/isValid report "not closed", even with bogus credentials

Tags: java, h2

I've built an H2 in memory database for short term storage.  I connect to the database from a short Java stub and test to make sure I have connected successfully.  Since it's quite short, I've included the code in full. I've used both .isClosed and isValid(0).  Is closed always always comes back in the negative (meaning not closed) and isValid(0) always answers in the positive (meaning not closed).  They both behave that way whether I use valid credentials or bogus

```
public class H2SeeWhatICabBreak {

public static Connection getConnection()   {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", "<username>");
    connectionProps.put("password", "<password>");
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/tickets");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection dbCTX = getConnection();

        if (dbCTX == null ) {
            System.err.println("Got back a null, good bye!!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        if (dbCTX.isClosed())
        {
            System.err.println("There's something rotten in River City");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Got connection");
        }

        System.err.println("Looks like we did it??");


    }
}
```

Any ideas at all?

Comment: You are not making use of `connectionProps`, so you are not actually using any credentials when making the connection. I think that means you are connecting with the default user (`sa`?)

Comment: `jdbc:h2:~/tickets` is not a in memory database, it's creating the database in your user's home directory and naming it `tickets`.  You need to take a look at [In-Memory Databases](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases).  The basic URL is `jdbc:h2:mem:`

Comment: @Glenn I converted your comment to an answer, because it _is_ the right answer. I know you should get the points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create and set `connectionProps`, but you don't actually *use* it. Your code is equivalent to the following. Please note the default username and password for H2 are an empty string.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/tickets");
```

or

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/tickets", "", "");
```

or

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/tickets", null);
```

or

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/tickets", new Properties());
```

What you want to do is either:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/tickets", 
    "<username>", "<password>");
```

or (more complicated):

```
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", "<username>");
connectionProps.put("password", "<password>");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/tickets",
    connectionProps);
```